# Spark equivalent for Kafka KTable?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

We have a KStream (sourced from a Kafka Topic) which has messages that look like this:
**Newer-messages**.....(Key1, val11) (Key2, val20) (Key1, val10).....**Older-messages**

We convert this KStream to a KTable so we have the latest value for each key:

```
KEY     VALUE 
-------------
Key1    val11
Key2    val20
```

How do I do the same exact thing in Spark, with the assumption that my Spark Streaming App can consume from the same Kafka Topic ?

Comment: Spark doesn't have such a thing. You would have to dump all executors to a database that de-dupes the keys.